# print choice command output batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have this type of command but I want to print the result
command below:

```
ECHO    Access to this system is restricted to authorized personnel for authorized business purpose only!!
CHOICE /M "Do you want to continue"
If Errorlevel 2 GoTo N

:Y
ECHO.
ECHO    You choose: YES


set /p id=Enter Name/ID:
ECHO Hello %id%

timeout /t 5

GoTo ErrorFunc

:N
Echo.
Echo    You choose: NO and you are required to exit from cmd !
Echo.

ECHO EXITING IN 5 SECOND

timeout /t 5
exit

test.bat > C:\test.log
```

If I type `Y` and print the result, it will stuck the result below:

> Access to this system is restricted to authorized personnel for
>   authorized business purpose only!! Do you want to continue [Y,N]?

Any idea for a solution?

Comment: What is the question you are wanting answered?

Comment: my question is i want my batch file choice command to have output and the output answer

Answer (score 0):

To add selections to your question, simply use

```
CHOICE /C:yn /M "Do you want to continue?"
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 GOTO Y
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 2 GOTO N
```

ERRORLEVEL 1 indicates the first selection which is `/C:`**y**`n`, ERRORLEVEL 2 indicates the second selection which is `/C:y`**n**.